# What is the the damage die of a punch or kick?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, unarmed-combat

Probably an easy question but I could not find the answer for it anywhere.

Our group have the Heroes of Fallen X books, the Dungeon Master Kit and the Monster Vault and although the DMK says that you use Melee Basic Attack to make an unarmed strike it doesn't say anywhere which die to use for the damage (the same is true for improvised weapons which are also mentioned)...

So what is the the damage die of a punch or kick?

PS: Talking about die, what is the damage die to initiative rolls? None of the books say it, I guess it is a d20, but I've seem people using d10.

Comment: Here it is only mentioning the PHB, and although I guess it should be the same, Essentials did made some changes to the core D&D4e.

Comment: I'm noting that (according to the Wizards website) the DMK contains a 235 page book of rules AND suggestions, while the Rules Compendium contain 320 pages of JUST rules. It's possible that rule wasn't included.

Comment: @WesleyObenshain, thats what I though (I don't have the Rules Compendium). I just found it odd that they didn't include something as basic as that.

Comment: I find the rules compendium more usefull than the DM book actually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unarmed attack is an Improvised Melee Weapon. It does d4 + Strength modifier damage and does not have a proficiency bonus.  See also *[What are some good stats to use when a player is attacking without a weapon (using fists)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8395/what-are-some-good-stats-to-use-when-a-player-is-attacking-without-a-weapon-usi)*

Initiative is d20 + initiative bonus.